# Flex mobile project Option

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a problem with Flash builder, I can't find the "Flex mobile project option in the list"
 How can I install it?

Comment: on 4.6 for sure is File->New->Flex Mobile project. i would assume that there is something wrong with your installation else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "mobile Project" option is not available in Flash Builder 4.  You'll have to upgrade to Flash Builder 4.5 or 4.6.

You may be able to do something with a normal Flash Builder 4 project, set up the multiple SDK Feature to use Flex 4.6, and manually add the mobile libraries.  I think you'll have to use command line tools to actually create release builds, though.